# No able to change English word "BAG" in the homepage menu

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, multistore, frontend, view

I've an e-commerce site in Magento 1.9 with two version: English and French.
I've to change some words in both English version and in the French.
For example, in the English version, I've to change word "BAG" shown in the following image:
[image]

I've to replace "BAG" with "SHOPPING BAG" but, inserting string "BAG", "SHOPPING BAG" (or "bag","shopping bag", or "Bag", "Shopping bag") into translate.csv of the theme (in the English folder) any change is shown in the frontend.
Activating path hints for the English version I notice that the phtml file that builds the block that contains this menu is the following:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="<?php echo $this->getContentType() ?>" />
<title><?php echo $this->getTitle()?></title>
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($this->getDescription()) ?>" />
<meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($this->getKeywords()) ?>" />
<meta name="robots" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($this->getRobots()) ?>" />
<link rel="icon" href="<?php echo $this->getFaviconFile(); ?>" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo $this->getFaviconFile(); ?>" type="image/x-icon" />
<?php
    $currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
    if (preg_match('/^https/', $currentUrl)) {
        $currentUrl = str_replace('https://', 'http://', $currentUrl);
    }

    $exclusions = array(
        'checkout/',
        'customer/account/'
    );
    $regexUrl = '/^' . str_replace(array('/', '.'), array('\\/', '\\.'), Mage::getBaseUrl() . '(?:(?:' . implode(')|(?:', $exclusions) . '))') . '/';
    if (!preg_match($regexUrl, $currentUrl)) {
        echo '<link rel="canonical" href="' . $currentUrl . '" />';
    }
?>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var BLANK_URL = '<?php echo $this->helper('core/js')->getJsUrl('blank.html') ?>';
    var BLANK_IMG = '<?php echo $this->helper('core/js')->getJsUrl('spacer.gif') ?>';
//]]>
</script>
<![endif]-->

<?php echo $this->getCssJsHtml() ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml() ?>
<?php echo $this->getIncludes() ?>
```

I think that there are some function (may be getHtmlChild()) that overwrites my translation because other words are translated adding new strings into traslate.csv.

Which file or function I've to change to see "shopping bag" in the frontend of my site? Why some words are changed with translate.csv and others not?
Can you help me, please?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

For translate any string you passed should be like :

```
<?php echo $this->__('Text here'); ?>
```

Then only it translate from CSV.

Comment: thanks..Have I to add $this->__('Bag'); or have I to find it? Where have I to add or find it?

Comment: when you `echo` your Bag at that place you need to set the string in this formate

Comment: or you can override and set all menu string in this formate

Comment: have I to change echo $this->__('bag') with echo $this->__('shopping bag') in the phtml file that builds the block? and then have I to add in traslate.csv of French language (for example) a string like "Shopping bag","Panier"? Is it correct?

Comment: yes, correct. after that you can replace Shopping bag with any string from csv.

Comment: thank you very much.. last information.. since I'm a beginner on Magento 1.9  I want be very sure that replacing 'bag' into function __('bag') with 'shopping bag' I don't create some problem in this code..

Comment: don't worry there will be no issue to rewrite label

Comment: If your problem is being solved you can make my answer correct